# Boost.Python.ArgumentError

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am learning python recently,this error happened when I call a function.Hope someone can help me.
In C++:

```
typedef struct   
{  
    char words[10];  
}keywords; 
typedef struct   
{  
    keywords *kws;  
    unsigned int len;  
}outStruct;
int test(outStruct *o)  
{  
    unsigned int i = 2;  
    o->kws = (keywords *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 10 * i);  
    strcpy(o->kws[0].words, "The First Data");  
    strcpy(o->kws[1].words, "The Second Data");  

    o->len = i;  
    return 1;
}  
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyTest)
{
    def("test", test); 
}
```

in python:

```
class keywords(Structure):  
    _fields_ = [('words', c_char *10),]  
class outStruct(Structure):
     _fields_ = [('kws', POINTER(keywords)), ('len', c_int),]  
test(byref(o))
```

error:
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
     Hello.test(Hello, CArgObject)
class outStruct(Structure):
    *fields* = [('kws', POINTER(keywords)), ('len', c_int),]

I googled it around for hours and i didn't came up with any good solution.
I want to get structure in python.
thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't mix boost.python and ctypes. Wrap your C structures by boost.python too.